# Adding onClickListeners to a list view andrioid

Tags: java, android

I have two java classes below that make a customListView. I got the code from somebody I'm working on an app with but I don't really understand her code. I want to add buttons that will bring you to an new activity when they are clicked, and change the text of "Description of "+itemname[positionof] to be different for each section(she has them all grouped so I can't change each individually).

I know that you can do something like

```
public void onLeaderboardClick(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , Leaderboard.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

to start the new activites but as I've said above I'm just not sure how to split them up indivually so each can have a diffeernt onClickValue

```
public class ListMainActivity extends Activity {
        ListView list;
        String[] itemname ={
                "Capture The Flag",
                "Leaderboard",
                "Log out"};

    Integer[] imgId={
            R.drawable.capturetheflag,
            R.drawable.leaderboard,
            R.drawable.logout,
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_main);

        CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgId);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String Selecteditem= itemname[+position];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Selecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final Integer[] imgid;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;
}
public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    extratxt.setText("Description of "+itemname[position]);
    return rowView;
};
}
```

Comment: I believe you can set an onClickListener inside the `getView` of the `CustomListAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add individual on click listener to every element in the list item by specifying them in the custom adapter

[How do i call onclick listener of a button which resides in listview item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941374/how-do-i-call-onclick-listener-of-a-button-which-resides-in-listview-item)

View this question it might be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a button into row layut layout.
Then in getView() method of Adapter class :

```
Button btnClick= (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
btnClick.setOnClickListener(@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //todo something with each button
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking back at this question, I ended up making a switch statement

Answer (score 0):

```
       # In your Adapter Class while inflating xml add a buttons as required 
     #   and get the references for that buttons then write onClick on #that button in your getView method of Adapter 


    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    Button button =(Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   // Do your Work 

Launch the Required Intent 
                }
            });

        txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
        extratxt.setText("Description of "+itemname[position]);
        return rowView;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `rowView.setOnClickListener()` in the getViewMethod of the class custom adapter and inside that you can then specify which activity you wanna go based on the position of the view.